# IMovie 10 Transitioning pictures over a video

Tags: imovie, macos

I am working on iMovie 10 on Mavericks.

I am creating a movie that has a video.  At times during the video I overlay sets of pictures.  I can transition nicely into the picture sets but I cannot seem to find a way use transitions between pictures in the sets.  I try to drag transitions down to the pictures which are on top of the video but it iMovie won't let me do this.  I would like to have nicer transitions between my pictures.